# How do I make a certain render layer a "Background" render layer?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

When you do a VFX scene and click the button "setup tracking scene", it automatically makes 2 render layers: a "Foreground", and a "Background" render layer. And the background render layer just renders the shadow without having to uncheck "Camera" in object's visibility settings and stuff. I'm wondering: is there a way that I can manually make certain layers "Background" layers?